# How to make this json regex greedy

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I have a regex like this in my json file

```
"body": {
   "content": "<div class=(?:\"|')content(?:\"|') [^>](.*?)</div>\\;content:\\1",
}
```

As of now its only match first content div.

Can someone tell me how to make it greedy?

Comment: what html are you trying to match?

Comment: Do you want it to match all content until the last </div>?

Comment: If you want it to match up to to `</div>` that matches with the openining `<div class="content" >` you're going to have to use something more powerful than regex. Regex can't count. If you're using Javascript in a browser you can just use the native DOM.

Comment: @seanmk yes. Also I want to match every div that has content class using the global (g) modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*?` is a non-greedy (or lazy) quantifier. To make it greedy just remove the `?`:

```
"body": {
   "content": "<div class=(?:\"|')content(?:\"|') [^>](.*)</div>\\;content:\\1",
}
```

Of course, as has been said many times before, you [shouldn't use regular expressions to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1715579).

To use the global mode, simply specify it when you're creating your RegExp, either like this:

```
"body": {
   "content": /<div class=(?:"|')content(?:"|') [^>](.*)</div>\\;content:\\1/g,
}
```

Or like this:

```
"body": {
   "content": new RegExp("<div class=(?:\"|')content(?:\"|') [^>](.*)</div>\\;content:\\1", "g"),
}
```

Of course at this point, it's no longer pure Json. Really, I'd recommend specifying the flags elsewhere. For example, in whatever code you have which actually does the html processing.

Comment: Ok got it. Now can you tell me how to match every content class using the global (g) modifier ?